# Passing data saved in a plist file to a widget in swiftUI

Tags: swift, class, swiftui, data-modeling

My app has a main class called DataManager which I use to handle the data that the user insert in the app.

This class has a main array "storage" where all the data is saved and every time a new values is inserted this class has a function to save the value in a file plist and update the View.

```
// example of my DataManager class

class DataManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    static let shared = DataManager()
    
    @Published var storage : [CovidTestModel] = []
    typealias Storage = [CovidTestModel]
    
    var filePath : String = ""
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        caricaDati() // load data
        
        firstStartSetting()
    }

 // functions of the class to run handle the data
}
```

I want to include for my app a Widget in order to display the last entry record saved in the storage array, but I can't find the way to pass the data to the widget.

Below my trial code but noting is loaded, is first time I'm looking into Widget how can I pass the data save in my storage array to the Widget. ()

```
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import Intents

struct Provider: IntentTimelineProvider {
    let dm = DataManager() //  looks like not loading
    
   
    
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry(lastTest: dm.storage.last, date: Date(), configuration: ConfigurationIntent())
    }

    func getSnapshot(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        let entry = SimpleEntry(lastTest: dm.storage.last, date: Date(), configuration: configuration)
        completion(entry)
    }

    func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []

        // Generate a timeline consisting of five entries an hour apart, starting from the current date.
        let currentDate = Date()
        for hourOffset in 0 ..< 5 {
            let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: hourOffset, to: currentDate)!
            let entry = SimpleEntry(lastTest: dm.storage.last, date: entryDate, configuration: configuration)
            entries.append(entry)
        }

        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
    }
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let lastTest : CovidTestModel?
    let date: Date
    let configuration: ConfigurationIntent
}

struct NAT_WidjetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(entry.lastTest?.expireOn ?? "NOT Working")
    }
}

@main
struct NAT_Widjet: Widget {
    let kind: String = "NAT_Widjet"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        IntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: ConfigurationIntent.self, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            NAT_WidjetEntryView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("My Widget")
        .description("This is an example widget.")
    }
}

struct NAT_Widjet_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NAT_WidjetEntryView(entry: SimpleEntry(lastTest: CovidTestModel(id: "3432", location: nil, valitidityHours: 0, validityDays: 2, isValidyBy: 0, dateInDate: Date()), date: Date(), configuration: ConfigurationIntent()))
            .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemSmall))
    }
}
```

When I open the app I see all the data saved, but nothing been loaded on the widget.

Comment: You don't appear to be showing any of the code relevant to loading a `plist`. My guess (not being able to see your code) is that you aren't storing the `plist` in a container accessible to both the app and the widget. In needs to be in an [App Group Container](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_application-groups)

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes the issue was exactly that, I did't implement the App Group Container